# Credible intervals for probability that posteriors lie on opposite sides of zero

Tags: probability, bayesian, classification

Please help me with this classification question.

Say I run an experiment where I have a treatment and control group. I then measure some feature, $x$,  of both groups and use MCMC to sample the posterior distribution of each group's mean $x$. I then classify the posterior draws of each group's $\overline{x}_i$ as belonging to either state A or state B depending on whether they cross some arbitrary fixed decision boundary (e.g., at $x = 0$). From this, I want to know the probability that the treatment caused my population to shift from state A to state B or vice-versa. Is the answer as simple as $p(\overline{x}_{control} > 0) \times p(\overline{x}_{treatment} < 0)$?

E.g., in the example pictured below, I have $p(\overline{x}_{control} > 0) = p(\overline{x}_{treatment} < 0) = 0.75$ such that the probability that the two distributions lie on opposite sides of zero is $0.75^2 = 0.56$.

Is there anything else I can say about the probability that these two posteriors lie on opposite sides of zero? Some credible interval, perhaps? I'm missing something obvious.

[image: example image]

Comment: Please clarify A and B. Is it *just* a classification rule based on an arbitrary boundary? Or does it somehow reflect the reality in the experiment, e.g., whether a patient's state improved?

Comment: Yes, the former. The boundary is just a previously derived fixed point that could represent e.g. diseased versus non-disease state.

Comment: And $x$ might be, for example, the blood pressure of the patient?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Any physical trait associated with being in states A or B